# Save trace of deep first search

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I'm searching for some data in one web page which has kind of tree structure.

The web page contains categories, each one of these categories can contain another categories or be a leaf (it contains particular data).

So the most simple way is probably to use recursion to search in this structure. But I want to save the trace of each leaf when it is found.

So here is the example:

```
url_of_1st_level_cat -> url_of_2nd_level_cat -> url_of_3rd_level_cat -> leaf
```

I want to be able to get whole trace of the leaf when I processing this leaf.

So when I get some leaf, I can do for example `find_trace(leaf)` which returns:

```
[url_of_1st_level_cat,url_of_2nd_level_cat,url_of_3rd_level_cat]
```

Here is a pseudocode of the recursive function which is searching for leafs:

```
def find_leafs_of_category(self,url):


   subcategories = self.get_subcategories(url)
   for subcategory in subcategories:
        if is_leaf(subcategory):
            # DO STUFF

        else: self.find_leafs_of_category(subcategory)
```

Do you have any idea of good and simple solution of this problem?

EDIT: The tree should be ordered so when some problem appears, it can continues from where it ended.

**More elaborated:**

( AAC, AAB are not real names of categories, they can't be traced by splitting their names in real)

```
A - AA ...
  - AB ...
  - AC - ACA ...
       - ACB ...
       - ACC ...
       - ACD - leaf1
             - leaf2
          - leaf3
          ...
```

1. I use method `find_leafs_of_category(A)`
2. Now, I want to do stuff with this leafs. So it process `leaf,leaf,leaf...leaf1,leaf2` and suddenly connection has been interrupted. To be able to continue I have to remember that It already processed all leafs of `A - AA ...` , `A - AB...` `A - AC - ACA ...`, `A - AC - ACB ...`, A - AC - ACC ... and from `A - AC - ACD`, the leafs which has been processed are `leaf1` and `leaf2`... So it has to be able to get the trace, which is `A - AC - ACD - leaf3` and continue from this point.

Comment: so, you can obtain the subcategories by splitting the url of the leaf? i.e: a/ab/abc/leaf1 ?

Comment: @le_vine No I definitely can't do that. I have to remember the trace during the searching.

Comment: ow, that's sadly out of my python comfort zone :(

Comment: You can append all your already processed categories and finish up with  leaf which you have found and store it list somewhere.
`['A', 'C', 'D', 'leaf1']`

So after interruption you can go forward from your last list.

Answer (score 1):

I've thought of a possible solution. 
It's actually pseudocode, so it will not work "as is", but i think you can get the idea out of it!

```
class Leafer(object):
    start_url = str
    last_visited_url = str
    leafs = []

    def find_leafs(self, url, subcategories=[]):
        self.last_visited_url = url
        new_sub = url.get_subcategories()
        for sub in new_sub:
            if is_leaf(url):
                self.leafs.append(Leaf(subcategories))
            else:
                self.find_leafs(sub, subcategories.append_sub)

class Leaf(object):
    subcategories = []
```

is it something that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a tuple of those elements to the recursive call, and in the next level, you simply add the current level to the tuple when you pass it. Something like this:

```
def find_leafs_of_category(self, url, path):
    subcategories = self.get_subcategories(url)
    for subcategory in subcategories:
        if is_leaf(subcategory):
            # DO STUFF

        else:
            next_path = path + (url,)
            self.find_leafs_of_category(subcategory, next_path)
```

Of course you have to pass an empty tuple in the first call to make this work, or alternatively, set the default value of the parameter to `None` and check it to initialize it:

```
def find_leafs_of_category(self, url, path = None):
    if path is None:
        path = (,) # empty tuple
```